# JSON Invalide primitive

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-ajax

I want to passing my number of seat to TryJSIN.aspx in function test().
but I have error, when I use type 'GET' then I have error

> "Invalid JSON primitive: 1-9."

1-9 is noSeat value.
but when I change to 'POST' I have error

> An attempt was made to call the method 'test' using a POST request, which is not allowed.

please check my following code. This is when I use get type

```
  var sid = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "TryJSON.aspx/test",
        type: "GET",
        data: {noSeat: sid},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        success: function (response) {
          // var arr = JSON.parse(response.d);
            console.log(arr);            
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("sorry, there was a problem!");
            console.log("error");
        },
        complete: function () {
            console.log("completed");
        }

    });
```

and this following ajax when I use POST type

```
var sid = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "TryJSON.aspx/test",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({'noSeat': sid}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
          // var arr = JSON.parse(response.d);
            console.log(arr);            
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("sorry, there was a problem!");
            console.log("error");
        },
        complete: function () {
            console.log("completed");
        }

    });
```

and this is my c# code

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static string test(string noSeat)
    {
        return noSeat;
    }
```

Please help me. I'm pretty new in c# ajax and jQuery. so I need a lot of help

**UPDATE:**
I Edit my code after first comment. but it show the same.

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static string test(string noSeat)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(noSeat).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You aren't returning JSON.

Comment: I used to use json serializer but it still error with same comment @SLaks

Comment: What response body do you see in the dev tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use `POST`, I not allowed to use `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]` because it for `GET` type. then the data must use `JSON.stringify` when I use `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` because it thinks that I send JSON whereas I send string data. so I need to convert it to JSON first.

```
var sid = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    //console.log(sid);
    $.ajax({
        url: "TryJSON.aspx/test",
        type: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'noSeat': sid }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            var arr = JSON.parse(response.d);
            objData = new Array();
            objData = arr;
            for (i = 0; i < objData.length; i++)
            {                 
                alert(objData[i].noBooking +" "+ objData[i].noSeat);
            }                                           
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("sorry, there was a problem!");
            console.log("error");
        },
        complete: function () {
            console.log("completed");
        }
```

this is how to solve on C#

```
[WebMethod]
   // [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static string test(string noSeat)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "Select noBooking,noSeat FROM booking WHERE noSeat = '" + noSeat +"' AND statusBooked = 1";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<booking> BookList = new List<booking>();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            booking bookClass = new booking();
            bookClass.noBooking =(int)dr[0];
            bookClass.noSeat = dr[1].ToString();
            BookList.Add(bookClass);
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(BookList).ToString();
    }
```